# Stopping GeoCoordinateWatcher After Accurate Location Has Been Found

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

The `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class allows me to continually be updated with the users current location. The `WatcherOnPositionChanged` event will be raised both when

1. An initial location is found
2. The accuracy is improved
3. The user physically moved beyond the defined threshold

I need to find the users position as accurate as possible, and then stop the watcher effectively ignoring whether the user is moving. However, there seems to be no way to extinguish the last two type of updates.

Several approaches comes to mind. The first update is always the cache from last time the GPS was used, the second appears to be an inaccurate guess and the third appears to be the final accurate location (at least on my device). Depending on this to be true for all devices seems unreliable at best. Another approach could be to wait a fixed amount of time before settling for the location. For example wait 10 seconds, and then take the latest location.

My first approach was to update and display the data everytime the location changed. However, this was very troublesome for two reasons. The location changes several times the first few seconds and secondly when the users position changed rapidly i.e. when sitting in a moving car the loading would become very annoying.

What is the best approach to find the user's location as accurately as possible, and then shut down the watcher?

Answer (score 1):

On the GeoCoordinate object you get from the GeoCoordinateWatcher, there's two properties: VerticalAccuracy and HorizontalAccuracy, which give the error magin in meters. Just ignore the coordinates until the accuracy properties are low enough for your needs.

Comment: This isn't quite enough. The GPS doesn't continue to improve. It improves to some point and then it stops. Sometimes this is to a ~6/6 meter accuracy, sometimes its a much lower accuracy. So if I wait for a high accuracy I might wait forever.

Comment: Then start a background thread, and make it sleep for as much time as you're ready to wait. After that time, if you still haven't got a precise enough position, take the last one. I don't believe there's a way to predict whether the GPS will be able to have a precise fix or not, I don't see how it would be possible.